# Weblinks which opens flow fails to return back to record with "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

Till now we have used `retURL` like this: 
`<url>/flow/TEST********?recordId={!Task.Id}&retURL=/{!Task.Id}</url>`

Check the forward slash `/` after retURL=, this was working till day before yesterday, without any issue.

But after yesterday I see this started failing with `Internal Server Error` and the flow was not able to return to the task Id. I was able to resolve by removing the forward slash `/` so my url now looks like this: 
`<url>/flow/TEST********?recordId={!Task.Id}&retURL={!Task.Id}</url>`

I read the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_url_retURL.htm&type=5) and saw that `/` is not mentioned, but the strange part ot it was working from past 6 months like this.

So my question is was there any update from salesforce or is there any link to forum where I can check if it will fail with `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` when we add `/`?

Comment: Do you see any GACK ID along with ISE?

Comment: I have an error Id `1584084529-18461 (-1449679492)` , I know I can raise a SF case, but they will say in documentation its not written to use `/`. If I remove it it works fine.

Comment: The GACK points to `MalformedURLException`. I'll check with the related team internally and let you know if something changed

Comment: This started happening in Prod from today. So now I am sure something got changed from Salesforce without notifying us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a known issue for this breaking change

[Internal Server Error when running flow via URL](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002iUTpQAM)

You identified the workaround (remove `/`), but this will be fixed so what previously worked will continue to work

It's currently slated for Spring '22 Patch 9.3 (delivered to some instances at the time of this writing) so it should be fixed soon for all.

Comment: Also, see https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/872

Comment: Yep saw that earlier today.Thanks